# How to migrate to a larger database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migrate

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails but am starting to do more development in that area. My question is, if I build a simple application that only has about 20 users and a couple thousand rows worth of content and then that number explodes to the point where I need to move to another database how does this work in RoR? What I am really looking for is a description of the process.

Comment: Wouldn't you be using a database like MySQL which is not language dependent?

Comment: I usually start my rails projects off using SQLite3 which is find for most of my projects, my question is when a project gets larger and I need to move to a DB like mySQL what is the process involved in migrating?

Comment: Its probably best to just start with a MySQL database, it lowers access time, supports concurrency, and has more flexibility.

Comment: It kinda depends on how you host your app. You should check out heroku and see how databases are managed from shared to dedicated postgres servers.

Comment: Heroku is generally where I host my apps that are just starting out. If I need to upgrade to a larger database I am just wondering if there is a best practices kind of process that would allow me to easily migrate to a larger database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is database agnostic. So worry not, you can very easily switch if you ever need to :) (that is if you do not write lots of native queries of course)

Comment: Cool, so if I have 10,000 records in my database and want to migrate to mySQL rails provides a method for doing this?

Comment: You would just change the database.yml and install your new database gem :)